# Relaciones en mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Como puedo relacionar colecciones embebidas? Ejemplo; supongamos que tenemos las colecciones A, B , C y que B esta embebida en A, pero a su ves quiero relacionar B con C.

```
'use strict'
/*
   Module dependencies
*/
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

export default () => {

  let B = new Schema({
    ...
  })

  let A = new Schema({
    B: [B] // embed schema
  }, { collection: 'A' })

  return mongoose.model('A', A)
}
```

Ahora en otro archivo es al que llamo `C`:

```
'use strict'
/*
  Module dependencies
*/
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

export default () => {
  let C = new Schema({
    B: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'B'
    }
  })
  return mongoose.model('C', C)
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad, tu pregunta no es muy clara, ¿podrías agregar un poco mas de detalles por favor?

Comment: Acabo de especificarla un poco.

Comment: Ya luce mucho mejor, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas crear la referencia usando un objeto `Schema.ObjectId` que es el tipo de datos usado para el identificador de un documento en MongoDB. La propiedad `ref` indica **dónde** buscar dicho identificador.

En este ejemplo, creamos un esquema `EsquemaA` para crear el modelo `A` que tiene una referencia al modelo `B`.

```
var EsquemaA = Schema({
  refB: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'B'
  }
});

var EsquemaB = Schema({
  refC: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'C'
  }
});

var EsquemaC = Schema({
  // ...
});

mongoose.model('A', EsquemaA);
mongoose.model('B', EsquemaB);
mongoose.model('C', EsquemaC);
```

En este ejemplo, el campo `RefB` es una referencia al identificador del modelo `B`.

Ahora, para referenciarlo, debes usar el objeto que representa al documento referenciado. En este ejemplo, tenemos el objeto `b` que es un documento tipo `B`:

```
let b = new B();
b.save();
```

Ahora, creamos el documento `a` que es de tipo `A` y hacemos la referencia al documento `b` en la propiedad o campo `refB`:

```
let a = new A();
a.refB = b;
a.save();
```

Dado que es solo una referencia a un `ObjectID` de un documento real, Mongoose tiene que rellenar la instancia de A con la instancia de B. Para hacerlo debes decirle a Mongoose que rellene el objeto `A` usando el método `populate()` cuando recupere el documento.

Eso ya depende de tí y no es lo que estás preguntando, pero una forma es usar el método `find()` para poblar la propiedad `refB`, por ejemplo:

```
A
  .find()
  .populate('refB')
  .exec(function(err, a) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Listo, no hay ninguna diferencia, excepto cambiar `var` por `let` .

Comment: Juan David, por favor sigue la guía llama [_"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"_](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para editar tu pregunta. Estoy usando ejemplos abstractos, igual que tu, para explicarte conceptos genéricos y es donde tienes problemas. Te recomiendo que uses tu código actual para que te resulte más fácil la comprensión y solución de tu problema. Tip: Donde ahora dice `A` pon una `B` y donde `B` pon una `C`.

Comment: Acabo de editar, en si es lo que quiero.

Comment: gracias. caí en cuenta con tu respuesta de como hacerlo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una forma de hacerlo, muchas gracias a todos.
dejo el link de la solución acá:
https://github.com/juandav/mongoose-relationships

Comment: me ayudo la respuesta de @toledano para caer en cuenta en que casi la tenia. :)